# Compilation Error Flutter ArCore plugin "Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected"

Tags: flutter, kotlin, arcore

I prepared everything in my flutter project for ArCore according to https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore?hl=en

(changes in AndroidManifest, build.gradle, gradle.properties).
When trying to run the app I get the following error:

> e:
> C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArcoreFlutterPlugin.kt:
> (32, 74): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was
> expected
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':arcore_flutter_plugin:compileDebugKotlin'.  Compilation error. See
>   log for more details

I tried deleting "?" next to Activity in ArCoreView.kt line

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```

but it didn't help. It looks like the problem is with the plugin. What other changes in its code should help? Is any of its version working correctly? Or what other thing to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using flutter version 3.3.1 which is null safe version
and arcore_flutter_plugin version is 0.0.11, which is not null safe plugin. please use null safe version.

please use below version of arcore_flutter_plugin

[arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.1.0-null-safety.3](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin/versions/0.1.0-null-safety.3)

Comment: Sadly, I still get this error 
`e: C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.1.0-null-safety.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArcoreFlutterPlugin.kt: (32, 74): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected`

Comment: Are you building app for windows?

Comment: No, for Android

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was downgrading flutter to last non null-safety version (2.10.5)